# Apache Camel Netty Tcp Component send and receive

Tags: java, tcp, apache-camel, netty

I'm struggleing while using the Apache Camel Netty Component. I want connect to a different system using a minimal route like this:

```
    from("netty:tcp://localhost:4314?clientMode=true")
    .log("${body}")
    .end();
```

My Problem is, that in order to receive any data I have to send some subscription message using the same connection.

A similar Problem was easy to solve, when the connection was made via ActiveMQ, where you could take the connection Factory and make a seperate connection for the subscription.

I have found this Question: [How to send a response back over a established TCP connection in async mode using Apache Camel Netty4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50043605/how-to-send-a-response-back-over-a-established-tcp-connection-in-async-mode-usin)

but it only work if you can receive something before you can reply.

How can I send data, using the same Channel as the route ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Hi @Ludi. Have you found a solution to this problem? I am struggling with the same issue. Please let me know, how did you solve that.

Comment: Hi, nope sadly I implemented the connection outside of camel and used a channel to get back into the 'camel world'